# methods to separate multiple count(*)s by external field

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I didn't know exactly what to call this question, so apologies if the title is confusing. I'm trying to generate a summary of user activity for a particular website. This query returns the total number of hits per type of page:

```
select
    count(case when internal_handle = 'content' then 1 else null end) as CONTENT,
    count(case when data = '/webapps/assessment/take/launch.jsp' then 1 else null end) as ASSESSMENTS,
    count(case when internal_handle = 'discussion_board_entry' then 1 else null end) as DISCUSSIONS,
    count(case when data = '/webapps/blackboard/execute/uploadAssignment' then 1 else null end) as BB_ASSIGNMENTS,
    count(case when data = '/webapps/turn-plgnhndl-BBLEARN/links/submit.jsp' then 1 else null end) as TII_ASSIGNMENTS,
    count(case when data = '/webapps/osv-kaltura-BBLEARN/jsp/courseGallery.jsp' then 1 else null end) as COURSE_GALLERY,
    count(case when data = '/webapps/osc-BasicLTI-BBLEARN/frame.jsp' then 1 else null end) as ECHO_360,
    count(case when internal_handle = 'check_grade' then 1 else null end) as MY_GRADES
from BBLEARN.ACTIVITY_ACCUMULATOR
where course_pk1 = (select pk1 from BBLEARN.course_main where course_id = '2014FA.BOS.PPB.445.A')
and user_pk1 in (select users_pk1 from BBLEARN.course_users where role = 'S' and crsmain_pk1 = course_pk1);
```

So the result is like:

```
CONTENT,ASSESSMENTS,DISCUSSIONS,BB_ASSIGNMENTS,TII_ASSIGNMENTS,COURSE_GALLERY,ECHO_360,MY_GRADES
5787,954,335,0,0,0,837,222
```

My goal, though, is to have it separated by hits per user. For instance, I'd want a result like:

```
USER_PK1,CONTENT,ASSESSMENTS,DISCUSSIONS,BB_ASSIGNMENTS,TII_ASSIGNMENTS,COURSE_GALLERY,ECHO_360,MY_GRADES
USER_A,250,79,41,0,0,0,66,7
USER_B,144,89,82,0,0,0,24,0
USER_C,174,45,23,0,0,0,58,1
--etcetera
```

I can imagine running the above query iteratively, but I'm not familiar enough with Oracle to do it effectively. How might I go about doing this? Or is there a better way to get the fields I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `group by`:

```
select user_pk1,
       count(case when internal_handle = 'content' then 1 else null end) as CONTENT,
       count(case when data = '/webapps/assessment/take/launch.jsp' then 1 else null end) as ASSESSMENTS,
       count(case when internal_handle = 'discussion_board_entry' then 1 else null end) as DISCUSSIONS,
       count(case when data = '/webapps/blackboard/execute/uploadAssignment' then 1 else null end) as BB_ASSIGNMENTS,
       count(case when data = '/webapps/turn-plgnhndl-BBLEARN/links/submit.jsp' then 1 else null end) as TII_ASSIGNMENTS,
       count(case when data = '/webapps/osv-kaltura-BBLEARN/jsp/courseGallery.jsp' then 1 else null end) as COURSE_GALLERY,
       count(case when data = '/webapps/osc-BasicLTI-BBLEARN/frame.jsp' then 1 else null end) as ECHO_360,
       count(case when internal_handle = 'check_grade' then 1 else null end) as MY_GRADES
from BBLEARN.ACTIVITY_ACCUMULATOR
where course_pk1 = (select pk1 from BBLEARN.course_main where course_id = '2014FA.BOS.PPB.445.A') and
      user_pk1 in (select users_pk1 from BBLEARN.course_users where role = 'S' and crsmain_pk1 = course_pk1)
group by user_pk1;
```

If `user_pk1` isn't what you mean by "user", then you might have to join in another table.

Comment: See, if I hadn't asked it here, I would have made it WAY more complicated. Thanks!